# I am unable to get image bytes from my JSON array, can anyone help me?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, android-volley

This is my JSON Array, I am unable to parse `ItemImage1` and `Bytes` from this JSON array.
Can any one help me.

```
   {"FetchAllItemsResult":[{"ItemID":5,
"ItemCategoryID":225,
"ItemCode":"1263",
"barcode":"0010000005",
"ItemDescription":"CAKE TRAY ROUND TEFAL 1 PCS (L) [RETAIL]",
"packingtypeid":1,
"ItemImage1":{"Bytes":[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,....]},
"sellingPrice":350.00,
"TaxPercentage":6.00},..]}
```

This is my Product Class.

```
public class Product{
@SerializedName("ItemID")
    int itemID;
    @SerializedName("ItemCategoryID")
    int itemCategoryID;
    @SerializedName("ItemCode")
    String itemCode;
    @SerializedName("barcode")
    String barCode;
    @SerializedName("ItemDescription")
    String itemDescription;
    @SerializedName("packingtypeid")
    int packingTypeID;
    @SerializedName("sellingPrice")
    double sellingPrice;
    @SerializedName("TaxPercentage")
    double taxPercentage;
    @SerializedName("ItemImage1")
    ProductImage itemImage;
}
```

This is ProductImage Class.

```
   public class ProductImage {

    @SerializedName("Bytes")
    byte[] itemImage;
}
```

This is ProductList class to hold the entire JSON Array.

```
  public class ProductList {
        @SerializedName("FetchAllItemsResult")
        List<Product> Products;
    }
```

I'm using `Volley` `GsonRequest<ProductList>`

There are no errors but I cannot get Image Bytes(`ItemImage1` and `Bytes`) from JSON array, please help me.

This is the output I'm getting for Bytes array.

```
[B@b2e761c8
```

Comment: `[B@b2e761c8` look right then as `[B` means a byte array.  Where is your print statement

Comment: I'm just logging the output using getter..
Log.i("ProductListReqImage",     prod.getItemImage().getItemImage()+"");

Comment: Bytes array is giving you the object's address which seems right. Another thing: Why not use some kind of string encoding instead of sending bytes as an array?

Comment: Log.i("ProductListReqImage", prod.getItemImage().getItemImage()[0]+""); should give you  137. Right?

Comment: @Akshay its giving me an error
06-04 04:46:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(14324): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Comment: That's not expected. You should get ArrayOutOfBoundsException in worst case scenario. Please check your logs once to see if theres a null value somewhere

Comment: @Akshay thanks man I figured it out, I forgot to loop through the byte[]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55048/discussion-between-gurupriyan-and-akshay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try printing the output using

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28byte%5b%5d%29)

Comment: I Used Arrays.toString(..) to get the String representation of the byte[].